# remote desktop not working from ubuntu to ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop

I have two computers which are both ubuntu.

I can RD into one box and i can see the screen.  However, I am not able to type anything or do any activity. for example if I minimize a window i dont see it happen. Then i close and RD again...then that window is minimized.

So I think in the background whatever I do is taking action but somehow the screen is not being changed.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Btw, I am on wifi laptop Remote desktoping into a desktop

Answer (score 1):

This is not caused by a flaky wireless link.  TCP does not work that way, random things can not just 'get lost'...

The problem is one I have seen before running certain remote desktop software at the same time as compiz.  vnc uses Xdamage these days to intelligently send updates to the client, but the offscreen rendering that compiz uses confuses vnc.

x11vnc can be ran with a "-noxdamage".  I'm not sure about the gnome vnc server.

In any case, I would try disabling compiz to confirm that that is the source of your problems.

Comment: I believe your answer is in the right direction.  i do have compiz on the desktop computer.  How do i completely disable compiz. I dread ever installing compiz.

Comment: System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Visual Effects -> None.

Comment: good tip on compiz, there've been lots of VNC/compiz problems on recent ubuntu releases.  i don't use compiz so it's easy to forget.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your screen updates are getting lost.  This could be due to a flaky wireless link.

First thing to try is attempt to force a screen refresh on your remote viewer client (the machine you're sitting at -- look around in the remote viewer menus for a "refresh screen" action).  Try it a few times; if it works, you should get a freeze-frame update of the remote desktop (your test, minimizing or maximizing one window, is perfect for this).

Second thing to try, particularly if the above works, is connecting the laptop to a wired network connection instead of the wireless.  Does the remote screen refresh normally?

If it works on the wired network, your wireless signal is having problems.  Does it work better on the wireless when you move the laptop closer to the access point?

Potential wireless trouble spots:  Is the signal strong enough?  Are you getting interference from neighboring devices?  (Your neighbor's wireless, your cell phone's bluetooth, your kitchen's microwave, your house's water pipes?)